# recursion on nested list need some support

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, nested-lists

---

I'm having trouble understanding the `else` statement in Python and how it's used in the context of flattening a list and working with recursion.

I came across this code snippet for flattening a list:

```py
def flatten_list(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return [lst]
    elif not lst:
        return []
    else:
        return flatten_list(lst[0]) + flatten_list(lst[1:])

my_list = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, [10, 11], 12], 13, 14]

print(flatten_list(my_list))
```

I tried running this code on PythonTutor to visualize the execution, but I'm still struggling to grasp how the algorithm works, particularly the recursive aspect. Could someone provide a clearer explanation or step-by-step breakdown of how this algorithm flattens a nested list using recursion? Thank you!

Comment: Yo dude you still have the reply of whatever LLM you used at the top :)

Comment: what is llm , i fixed text with gpt i forgot delete xd but idk what is LLM

btw i asked gpt but i dont quite understand

Comment: LLM = [Large Language Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model). ChatGPT is a LLM. I just wanted to notice you that you still have your ChatGPT text :) Its all good

Comment: ah thanks , my English is not good enough to meet stackoverflow standards so I needed help with the text but iam happy now @BoppreH
dude solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def flatten_list(lst):
```

How do you "flatten" an object? Well, *it depends* on what that object is.

---

```
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return [lst]
```

If the object is not a list, we assume it's already "flat". But we want to always return a list, so we wrap it in a list by itself (length 1) and return that.

By returning we stop execution and don't look at the next cases.

---

```
    elif not lst:
        return []
```

But if the object *is* a list, and it's **empty** (`not lst`), we return an empty list.

---

```
    else:
```

Now comes the tricky part. The object *is* a list (otherwise it'd be caught by the first `if`), and it's *not* empty (otherwise it'd be caught by the `elif`). So we have to flatten an actual list of objects.

But hey, it's progress!

---

```
        return flatten_list(lst[0]) + flatten_list(lst[1:])
```

Because we know the list is not empty, it'll always have a "first element". If the first element is a list, we'll flatten it, and if it's an object, we'll wrap it in a list. Either way it'll be flat.

Now, the rest of the list `lst[1:]` might or might not be empty. But that's ok, because `flatten_list` knows how to handle empty lists!

So we just repeat the process for the rest of the list, processing the first element of each "rest of list", until we process the whole list.

---

### Step-by-step example

Think of the case `[1, [2, 3]]`.

When you call `flatten_list([1, [2, 3]])`, you're passing a non-empty list, so the `else` branch will be executed. The recursion will then be:

```
flatten_list(1) + flatten_list([[2, 3]])
```

The first recursion calls `flatten_list(1)`, which returns `[1]` (because of the `elif` branch). So now we have

```
[1] + flatten_list([[2, 3]])
```

Remember this statNow, `flatten_list([[2, 3]])` is processing a list of lists. This list is not empty, so we execute the `else` branch again, which is equivalent to:

```
[1] + (flatten_list([2, 3]) + flatten_list([]))
```

Now we execute `flatten_list([2, 3])`, which is also non-empty, so our expression becomes:

```
[1] + ((flatten_list([2]) + flatten_list([3])) + flatten_list([]))
```

And we recurse again:

```
[1] + (((flatten_list(2) + flatten_list([])) + flatten_list([3])) + flatten_list([]))
```

This is looking complicated, but we're finally at simple cases: a non-list and and empty list. We know how to process those:

```
[1] + ((([2] + []) + flatten_list([3])) + flatten_list([]))
[1] + (([2] + flatten_list([3])) + flatten_list([]))
```

We now evaluate `flatten_list([3])`:

```
[1] + (([2] + (flatten_list(3) + flatten_list([]))) + flatten_list([]))
```

Which becomes:

```
[1] + (([2] + ([3] + [])) + flatten_list([]))
[1] + (([2] + [3]) + flatten_list([]))
[1] + ([2, 3] + flatten_list([]))
```

Finally, we have our last recursion call, on an empty list:

```
[1] + ([2, 3] + flatten_list([]))
[1] + ([2, 3] + [])
[1] + [2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Ta-da, a flat list!

Comment: thank you very much, thanks to you I understand very well.
good luck